# keith-wood Signature not working on production

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, signature

jQuery UI Signature  working on local but not working on live server
[image]
**javascript:**

```
    var sig = $('#sig').signature({syncField: '#signature64', syncFormat: 'PNG',svgStyles: true});
       $('#clear').click(function(e) {

           e.preventDefault();

           sig.signature('clear');

           $("#signature64").val('');
       });
```

**HTML code:**

```
     <label class="" for="">Signature:</label>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div id="sig" ></div>
                                        <br/>
                                        <button id="clear" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Clear Signature</button>
                                        <textarea  id="signature64" name="signed" style="display: none">

                                        </textarea>
```

**route:**

```
 Route::POST('bene/store/', [App\Http\Controllers\BeneficiaryController::class, 'store'])->name('beneficiary.store');
```

[image]
[image]
everything seems fine but whenever I submit my form got that error

[image]

thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Did you try to clear the routes cache?

Comment: yes i did everything

Comment: if i use  syncFormat: 'JSON' then its working time 
but I don't know how to convert that json code into image

Comment: even i check  php artisan route:list
and route is correct 
if I remove signature pad then everything  work fine

Comment: open `Inspect` at `network` tap, check if form sending post request and request data is alright.

Comment: i'm not sending request through ajax

Comment: `inspect` records every request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237683/discussion-between-hassan-raza-and-mohamed-gamal-eldin).

Comment: but after submit page redirect and network tab have not any record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase post max size in php.ini file then this issue will fixed.

Comment: Can you explain how this will solve the issue? The error says the `GET` method is not supported while it expect a `POST` method. In other words, it means that the html/js is submitting a GET request to `/bene/store`